# CSS Webkit Transition - Fade out slowly than Fade in

Tags: css, webkit, fade, css-transitions

This is what I have:

```
.box{
    background:#FFF;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s;
}

.box:hover{
    background:#000;
}
```

But this appends to both **onmouseover** and **onmouseout** actions, but isn't there a way to control them? Something like:

```
-wekbkit-transition-IN: background 1s;
-webkit-transition-OUT: background 10s;
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just redifine your transition in the over pseudo element.

```
.box{
    background: white;
    -webkit-transition: background 5s;
}
.box:hover{
    background: olive;
    -webkit-transition: background 1s;
}
```

Look my http://jsfiddle.net/DoubleYo/nY8U8/

Answer (score 0):

Either use an [animation](http://24ways.org/2009/css-animations) (only in webkit currently), or use JS to add and remove the properties, they will still animate.