# Quirky jQuery on rollover

Tags: jquery

My developer is having trouble creating a smooth and efficient transition on [this page](http://www.branard.com). Please roll over the logo "Clockrun" and notice how the text changes once fully visible (especially in Chrome) and how quirky the roll over affect is when rolling off and on the logo.

here is the jQuery being used. Is there a better way of doing this so the transition fades in and out much more smoothly?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery(".super_featured_desc").css("opacity",0);
        jQuery(".super_featured_logo").each(function(){
          jQuery(this).hover(
              function () {
                jQuery(this).children(".super_featured_desc").css("display","block");
                jQuery(this).children(".super_featured_desc").animate({"opacity": 1}, 400);
              },
              function () {
                jQuery(this).children(".super_featured_desc").css("display","none");
                jQuery(this).children(".super_featured_desc").animate({"opacity": 0}, 400);
              }
          )
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: It's not quirky for me in either Chrome nor FF.

Comment: If you roll off and on it continues to fade in and out. It also does not fade out correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try using stop:

`.stop(true, true)`  API: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

or look in here `effects`  http://docs.jquery.com/Effects you can add show with `slow` effect.

If you can flick me jsfiddle I can make it for you, hope this will help `:)`

**code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery(".super_featured_desc").css("opacity",0);
        jQuery(".super_featured_logo").each(function(){
          jQuery(this).hover(
              function () {
                jQuery(this).children(".super_featured_desc").css("display","block");
                jQuery(this).children(".super_featured_desc").stop(true, true) .animate({"opacity": 1}, 400);
              },
              function () {
                jQuery(this).children(".super_featured_desc").css("display","none");
                jQuery(this).children(".super_featured_desc").stop(true, true) .animate({"opacity": 0}, 400);
              }
          )
        });
    });
```

Comment: This actually works much better. But what about the disappearing when you roll off instead of the gradual fade out?

Comment: @TommyCoffee Glad it helped `:)` you should look for event called `fadeOut` and chain it accordingly. `:)` try like this `.fadeOut('slow');`

Comment: I don't know how this is done. This is code from my developer. how would I do that?

Comment: @TommyCoffee see here how: ==> there are sample of code with stop and fadeout ==>  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713665/using-fade-in-fade-out-with-jquery `:)`

Comment: @TommyCoffee +1 to you as well `:)`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a gradual fade on `mouseout` use a callback on the mouseout animation and insert your `jQuery(this).children(".super_featured_desc").css("display","none");` there:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            jQuery(".super_featured_desc").css("opacity",0);
            jQuery(".super_featured_logo").each(function(){
              jQuery(this).hover(
                  function () {
                    jQuery(this).children(".super_featured_desc").css("display","block");
                    jQuery(this).children(".super_featured_desc").stop(true, true) .animate({"opacity": 1}, 400);
                  },
                  function () {
                    jQuery(this).children(".super_featured_desc").stop(true, true) .animate({"opacity": 0}, 400, function(){
    jQuery(this).css("display","none");
    });
                  }
              )
            });
        });
```