# simple and effective way to fade in hover

Tags: html

I need help making an image fade into another image when i hover over. I want a transition fade when you hover over the image. 
I've tried several different ways already but they do not seem to work how i want.
The social icons on the bottom of the page are the ones i want to create a fade transition 
jquery/javascript/css whatever it takes.

thanks. so what do i need to do?

http://trulyamped.com/test/index.html

Comment: Post the 'several ways you've tried' here?

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: well i have tried the ways posted below and they are not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/Xm2Be/13/) 
from [Using fade in/fade out with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713665/using-fade-in-fade-out-with-jquery).

It should do what you need...

Html code:

```
<div class="fader">
<img class="something" src="http://placehold.it/300x300/000fff" />
<img class="something" src="http://placehold.it/300x300/fff000" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
window.onload=function(){
    $('.fader').hover(function() {
        $(this).find(".something").stop(true, true).fadeToggle();
    });
};
```

CSS:

```
.fader { display: inline-block; }
.fader img:last-child {
position: absolute;
top: 0; 
left: 0;
display: none;
}
```

Don't forget to add to the head 
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

If you want it to be slower add a number inside `.fadeToggle(600);`

Comment: Nice idea, here is just implementation (and small modification) - to work in this particular case: http://jsfiddle.net/ck34P/

Comment: i really do not know what i am missing, please let me know where i am going wrong http://trulyamped.com/test/duck.html

Comment: @TeoAlmonte, you are calling your function before the HTML is in place. Add `window.onload=function(){` code `};`. Just updated my answer.